# Espace single/double quotes inside replace function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove single and double quotes from a string of escaped characters.
It does no work for single quotes `'` or double autos `"`.

Please could somebody help please?

```
var mysting = escapedStr.replace(/^%22/g, ' '); //doesnt remove the double quotes

var mysting = escapedStr.replace(/^%27/g, ' '); //doesnt remove the single quotes

var mysting = escapedStr.replace(/^%3A/g, ' '); //does remove the SEMI COLON %3A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snipped of chained code:

```
escape(
 unescape( mysting ).replace( /['"]/g, "" )
)
```

Its small but should do what you need it to do.

Answer (score 1):

The `^` is an anchor indicating the start of the string.  That is, it will only do the replacement if the string *starts* with `%22`, etc.  Logically, it can only start with one thing (apparently a semi-colon).  I think you just want to remove the `^`.